# lookup with condition in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two collections. articles and bookmarks.

#### articles

```js
{
    _id: "5faa889ade5e0a6326a873d3",
    name: "article 1"
},
{
    _id: "5faa889ade5e0a6326a873d",
    name: "article 2"
}
```

#### bookmarks

```js
{
    _id: "5faa889ade5e0a6326a873d1",
    user_id: "5fc7b50da483a66a86aa7e9e",
    model_id: "5faa889ade5e0a6326a873d3"
}
```

I want to join article with bookmark. if user bookmarked a article.
what i have tried

```js
const aggregate = await Articles.aggregate([{
        $lookup: {
            from: "categories",  
            localField: "category_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "category_id"
        }
    },
    {

        $lookup: {
            from: "bookmarks",  
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "model_id",
            as: "bookmarks"
        }
    }
]);
```

but it will gives all bookmark for the article not only logged in user bookmark. so how can I add a condition.

```js
{ "user_id": objectId(req.user._id) } // logged user id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$lookup with pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) **starting from MongoDB v3.6**,

- let to pass localField `_id` as `model_id` variable, you can use the field inside lookup pipeline using $$ reference,
- pipeline to put `$match` stage and match your required conditions and `user_id` condition

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "bookmarks",
      let: { model_id: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$model_id", "$model_id"] },
            user_id: objectId(req.user._id)
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "bookmarks"
    }
  }
```

---

Other option for **MongoDB v3.4**,

- [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to iterate loop of `bookmarks` and get filtered bookmarks on the base of condition

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "bookmarks",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "model_id",
      as: "bookmarks"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      bookmarks: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$bookmarks",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$this.user_id", objectId(req.user._id)] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: i am getting error MongoError: arguments to $lookup must be strings, let: { model_id: "$_id" } is type object

Comment: can you confirm your mongodb version? might be your mongodb version below 3.6 and this feature if supprted from v3.6

Comment: ok got it. it's 3.4. it there any alternative

Comment: i think no you can do filter after your normal lookup stage, updating my answer with that option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226649/discussion-between-akash-kumar-verma-and-turivishal).

Answer (score 1):

You can have nested pipeline inside `$lookup`,

```
db.articles.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "bookmarks",
      let: {
        article_id: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$model_id",
                    "$$article_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$user_id",
                    "5fc7b50da483a66a86aa7e9a"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "bookmarks"
    }
  }
])
```

Here's a working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ocd38cwduRl)