# Mongoose query with pagination not working properly

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Mongo Version - v3.4
based on my last question - [lookup with condition in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65518294/lookup-with-condition-in-mongoose/65518498)

My query working on for page 1. but on the second page it gives empty result.

```js
const casestudies = await CaseStudy.aggregate([{
                $lookup: {
                    from: "categories",
                    localField: "category_id",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "category_id"
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    "updated_at": 0,
                    "category_id.updated_at": 0
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "bookmarks",
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "type",
                    as: "bookmarks"
                }
            },
            {
                $addFields: {
                    bookmarks: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$bookmarks",
                            cond: { $eq: ["$$this.user_id", req.user ? objectId(req.user._id) : ''] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            { $sort: { "publish_date": -1 } },
            { $limit: pageSize },
            { $skip: (page - 1) * pageSize }
        ]);
```

What's wrong in my query.
Please help me.

Comment: Use `$sort`, `$skip` and `$limit` at the top and swap the `$limit` and `$skip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so as suggested by @Ashh issue in order of `sort`,`$skip`, `$limit`.
so the correct query should be.

```js
{ $sort: { "publish_date": -1 } },
{ $skip: (page - 1) * pageSize },
{ $limit: pageSize }
```